# top-level await in a module prevents `onload` from firing

Tags: javascript, firefox, async-await, indexeddb

I'm seeing that the `load` event won't fire if I `await` for an IndexedDB opening at the top level in an indirectly loaded module.

If I remove the `await`, the `load` handler is called as expected.
If I keep the `await` but replace the `openDB` call with a dummy promise (like `Promise.resolve(42)`), the `load` handler is called as expected.

What is going on, and how can I debug this?

index.html:

```html
...
<script type="module" src="js/ui_index.js" type="javascript/module"></script>
...
```

(it also contains an importmap, so all the imports work correctly)

ui_index.js:

```js
import * as db from "database";
...
window.addEventListener('load', () => console.log('onload'));
console.log('ui');
```

database.js:

```js
import { openDB } from "lib/idb";

//         ↓↓↓↓↓ *** THIS AWAIT ***
const db = await openDB("my-database-name", 4, {

    upgrade(db, old_ver, new_ver, tx) {
        console.log(`db.upgrade ${old_ver}→${new_ver}`);
    }
}

console.log('db:', db);
```

The `idb` module above is a [promises-based IndexedDB wrapper by Jake Archibald](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb/).

Console output with `await`:

```
db.upgrade 4→5
db: Proxy { <target>: IDBDatabase, <handler>: {…} }
ui
```

Console output without `await`:

```
db: Promise { <state>: "pending" }
ui
onload
db.upgrade 5→6
```

(The `db.upgrade` line, of course, is only present if I increment the DB version in the `openDB` call. It does not affect the `onload` behavior).

I am testing this in Firefox 120 and have not tried other browsers; I'm building a small web app for in-house use which will only be used with Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you do the await in the script body instead of declaring a function that does the await, this postponed the attaching of onload event listener, I believe it is still fired but before your event listener is attached.

May I suggest you something like this:

database.js:

```
import { openDB } from "lib/idb";

export default async function open() {
        const db = await openDB("my-database-name", 4, {
            upgrade(db, old_ver, new_ver, tx) {
                console.log(`db.upgrade ${old_ver}→${new_ver}`);
            }
        }
        console.log('db:', db);
}
```

ui_index.js:

```
import open from "database";
window.addEventListener('load', () => console.log('onload'));
console.log('ui');
open();
```

Comment: You're right! I added another 'load' handler in a `<script>` I inserted in index.html before the one importing ui_index.js, and it runs even with the `await` in place. Then I changed database.js to drop the `await` at `const db`, but added `export default await db`; this way both handlers run _and_ the imported db promise is already resolved. I think I'll restructure the database module to `export default await` an object and make the API its methods instead of loose functions.

Comment: I made a mistake in my haste and of course if I use `export default await db` as I said in my previous comment, it still delays the execution of the importing module. A correct implementation of the same idea is to export a function that constructs the object, just like the answer says. Just though I should mention this so as not to mislead possible future readers (I cannot edit my previous comment anymore).

Comment: Glad to see it works out!